react-native-pusher-push-notifications get notification payload when opened from quite state
I've implemented remote notifications using react-native-pusher-push-notifications and I'm able to receive the payload when the app is opened already but not when it is in quit state.
When I get a notification and the app is in quit state, clicking on the notification opens the app but I cannot see the payload.
I've followed the installation steps as described in the ReadMe: https://github.com/b8ne/react-native-pusher-push-notifications (i.e For android they said to skip autolink and all other installation-related settings for iOS and Android)
Then I have a pusher.ts file in which I'm initializing it as:
export const initPusher = async (): Promise<void> => {
        RNPusherPushNotifications.setInstanceId(Config.PUSHER_INSTANCE_ID)
    RNPusherPushNotifications.on("registered", () => {
        const callSetUserId = (): void => {
            const userId = useAuthStore.getState().user.id
            const pusherToken = useAuthStore.getState().pusherToken

            RNPusherPushNotifications.setUserId(
                userId.toString(),
                pusherToken,
                (error: any) => {
                    console.log("pusher setUserId error", JSON.stringify(error))
                    RNPusherPushNotifications.clearAllState()
                    if (retryCount < 3) {
                        retryCount++
                        callSetUserId()
                    }
                },
                () => {
                    console.log(
                        "pusher setUserId success:",
                        JSON.stringify({ userId, pusherToken }),
                    )
                },
            )
        }

        callSetUserId()
    })
}

THen in my Main Navigator file which is loaded from App.tsx I have:
    useEffect(() => {
        initPusher()
        useNotificationHandler()
    }, [])

The useNotificationHandler is where I have a use effect, which gets triggered only when the app is opened and not when it's in background or killed state.
    const handleNotification = (notification: any) => {
        console.log("notification: ", notification)

        // iOS app specific handling
        if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
            switch (notification.appState) {
                case "inactive":
                // inactive: App came in foreground by clicking on notification.
                //           Use notification.userInfo for redirecting to specific view controller
                case "background":
                // background: App is in background and notification is received.
                //             You can fetch required data here don't do anything with UI
                case "active":
                // App is foreground and notification is received. Show a alert or something.
                default:
                    break
            }
        } else {
            console.log("android handled notification...")
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        RNPusherPushNotifications.on("notification", handleNotification)
    }, [])

It's not working and there is no error, so I'm stuck at this point.
